# Make two different dataframes using parent dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split one dataframe into two different data frames based on one of the columns value

Eg: df(parents dataframe)

df has a column MODE with values swiggy , zomato

df1 with all the columns which has common with MODE = swiggy

df2 with all the columns which has common with MODE= Zomato

I know its simple, I am beginner, Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`df1 = df[df['MODE'] == 'swiggy']` and `df2 = df[df['MODE'] == 'Zomato']`.

This way, you will be filtering the dataframe based on the MODE column and assigning the resulting dataframe to new variables.